# How to debug js/varien/configurable.js

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

I made some changes to js/varien/configurable.js but they don't seem to work as expected, I open the file in a built in debugger in my browser and set a break point at desired location, however it looks like it is never reached. When I move my breakpoint to the start of function it stops at that breakpoint(meaning function is being called) however the usuall shortcuts to step into function does not work. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't modify core is files. It's easy to extend an existing class and if necessary call the parent method with $super.

Comment: However, if you use php Storm, there is a fantastic js debugger built in, I use it with Magento all the time.

Comment: I am quite new to Magento and I am self thought, so far I used simple notepad++ to edit files when needied. I haven't mande that many changes yet. I have no previous experience with php Storm, would you know of any good step by step guide how to set it up on Ubuntu server and how to start debugging magento application?

Comment: anyone help, where is the file exactly located?